# Angular2 & RxJS multiple HTTP calls - display as soon as first response returned

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm trying to use RxJS and Angular2 to build a search field. I have a simple text input field that I'm observing for valueChanges.

I then use the inputted value to call a first REST service which returns a search results object that contains a list of customers.

Then for each customer returned I call a second REST service to get the customer details and store the returned details in the customer object.

My screen then loops over the customers to display them.

But I have two problems that I can't seem to figure out:

1. I want the results to appear as soon as the first service returns
   and then update the screen when the second service returns but at
   the moment nothing displays until all the service calls are
   completed.
2. When someone changes the input field I want the results to disappear
   immediately but for some reason that is no happening and I can't
   figure out why e.g. if I enter in a search term that returns no
   matches, the results from the previous search remain on screen.

My code looks like:

```js
this.customers = this.term.valueChanges
            .filter(term => {
                return term !== null;
            })
            .switchMap(term => {
                return this.customerService.search(term)
            })
            .map(searchResults => {
                return searchResults.customers;
            })
            .flatMap(customers => {
                if (customers.length > 0) {
                    // this.customers = customers;
                    return Observable.forkJoin(
                        customers.map((customer: Customer) => {
                            return this.customerDetailService.getDetails(customer)
                                .map((details: any) => {
                                    customer.details = details;
                                    return customer;
                                });
                        }));
                }
                return customers;
            });
```

And the screen looks like:

```html
<div *ngIf="customers|async; let customers">

    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let customer of customers">

           {{customer.name}}
           {{customer.details.age}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Kevin.

Comment: Just a tip you may find helpful: you can write lambdas in shorter way, for example: .filter(term => term !== null)

Comment: Thanks. I've fairly new to using JS so still figuring it all out!

Comment: Interesting problem... `customers` stream should yield in 3 phases: An empty array when the user makes a new search, an array with incomplete `Customer` object and finally an array with complete `Customer` objects. The first solution that comes into my mind is by using `BehaviourSubject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `this.customers` ? A combination of the initial fetch and every update that comes later. So this should work :

```js
let search = this.term.valueChanges
  .filter(term => term !== null)
  .switchMap(term => this.customerService.search(term))
  .map(searchResults => searchResults.customers);

let details = search.switchMap(customers => {
  if (customers.length > 0) {
    // this.customers = customers;
    return Observable.forkJoin(
      customers.map((customer: Customer) => {
        return this.customerDetailService.getDetails(customer)
          .map((details: any) => {
            customer.details = details;
            return customer;
          });
      }));
  }
  return customers;
});

this.customers = Observable.merge(search, details);
```

Comment: just tried this but no luck. Behaves the exact same way as what I had originally.

Comment: At least, this is the right way, look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lxUgxzVr7vM5aPj2JGiD?p=preview)

Comment: Oh I think I didn't get your question, actually

Comment: you want to start displaying data just after this: `this.customerService.search(term)`, right ?

Comment: That's correct noodl3. As soon as I get the customer name I want to display it. I'm happy to wait then a few seconds to get the additional details from a second slower service.

Comment: You're just missing the wiping the previous result as soon as the user makes a new search. Should be trivial to do with that merge, though.

Comment: Actually it does not work as I thought, I kept my code of original answer and that is not the expected behavior. I'll edit...

Comment: I changed to use your `forkJoin` part which is what is needed... @olivarra1 no cleanup needed, as it is done automatically [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/lxUgxzVr7vM5aPj2JGiD?p=preview)

Comment: @n00dl3 Read the question, is a requisite from the OP. `2. When someone changes the input field I want the results to disappear immediately`. This doesn't happen automatically in your solution, but as I said, it's trivial to solve that.

Answer (score -1):

What about this? (look at my comment on your question for explanation behind)

```
this.customers = new Rx.BehaviourSubject([]);

this.term.valueChanges
    .filter(term =>  term !== null)
    .do(() => this.customers.onNext([]))
    .switchMap(term => this.customerService.search(term))
    .map(searchResults => searchResults.customers)
    .do((customers) => this.customers.onNext(customers))
    .switchMap(customers => {
        if (customers.length > 0) {
            // this.customers = customers;
            return Observable.forkJoin(
                customers.map((customer: Customer) => {
                    return this.customerDetailService.getDetails(customer)
                        .map((details: any) => {
                            customer.details = details;
                            return customer;
                        });
                }));
        }
        return customers;
    })
    .subscribe(
        (customers) => this.customers.onNext(customers),
        (err) => this.customers.onError(err),
        () => this.customers.onComplete();
    );
```

Comment: I don't see the point in using `BehaviorSubject` here. You should avoid using Subjects for external stream sources, as they are mutable. You can find an [interesting article](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx) on this topic. It's about RX.net, but it's the same underlying concept.